# grep command not showing any output in perl

Tags: perl

I have an array @files in which I have multiple .txt files. I am trying to grep all the lines that have the pattern "/home/[a-z]+" from the starting of the lines in those files. I am trying the below approach:

```
my @lines = grep (/^\/home\/[a-z]+/, @files);
chomp(@lines);
my @line = uniq(@lines);
```

but I do not get anything in the output when I try to print @lines.

Can someone please let me know what am I doing wrong in the grep command. Thanks.

Comment: The `LIST` argument for `grep` is not interpreted as a list of file names. It is interpreted as the `LIST` of text items that is searched. In other words, think of `LIST` as the lines in the files that you want to search. [perldoc -f grep](https://web.engr.uky.edu/~elias/tutorials/perldoc-html/functions/grep.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the following code sample which demonstrates an approach you have chosen.

It would be very helpful if you provided a sample of content `@files` array.

Note: there is no need to use `uniq(@lines)` as filesystem assumes uniq filenames in it's organization

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @files = <DATA>;
my @lines = grep( m!^/home/[a-z]+/!, @files);

say @lines;

__DATA__
/home/alex/work/samples
/home/philip/doc/asterix
/home/maria/bin/quick_search.c
/bin/grep
/sbin/test
```

Output

```
/home/alex/work/samples
/home/philip/doc/asterix
/home/maria/bin/quick_search.c
```

Sample code to filter matching pattern for list of files stored in an array `@files`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @files = qw/abc.txt, bcd.txt, cde.txt/;
my @lines;

for my $file (@files) {
    my @temp;
    
    open my $fh, '<', $file
        or die "Couldn't open $file";
    @temp = grep( m!^/home/[a-z]+/!, <$fh>);    
    close $fh;
    
    @lines = (@lines, @temp);
}

chomp(@lines);

say for @lines;
```

- [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks for the response. @files contains files abc.txt, bcd.txt, cde.txt and I want to grep the lines out of these files that are starting with /home like 

/home/john/abc
/home/john/xyz

Unfortunately the above solution is not working for me.

Comment: This solution reads the data from below `__DATA__`. It should not be hard to adapt the code to read lines from a set of files which you loop over and read.

Comment: Please see a sample code added to my answer based on provide additional information.

Comment: Yes the code is working for all the lines that has /home but without the ^ option in the line:

     @temp = grep( m!^/home/[a-z]+/!, <$fh>);

When I use the ^ option it doesn't display any data.

Comment: You need to investigate further as `^` means `begin of the string/line` [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)